# Add or delete a row of a table then put all the data in a JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new in Jquery & Angularjs.

I want to make a form with two buttons.

The first button name is = ***Row Creator*** and the second one name is = ***Submit***.

when i click on ***Row Creator button***, it creates a row of a table with 3 columns.
(1st column name=***Name***, 2nd Column Name=***Size***, and the 3rd column name=***Type***)

and any time when i click on that, it adds a new row.

at the end when i click on the ***Submit*** button, it send all of my rows data in a JSON file.

I have no idea about this. I need the code in Angularjs or JQuery or Javascript.

Thanks for sharing

```
    $scope.fileContent = "";
$scope.storeFile = function () {
    var saveFile = new dataStructure();
    var fileContent = $scope.fileContent.Content;
    saveFile.EntityInfo[0].Name = GUID() + "." + $scope.fileContent.FileName.split('.').pop(); //taking the name of the off and adding the GUID & splitting the postfix
    saveFile.EntityInfo[0].Type = "CUSTOMFILE";
    saveFile.EntityInfo[0].Size = $scope.fileContent.Size; //Taking the size of the file
    saveFile.EntityData = [
        {"Content": fileContent}
    ];

    var inputjsondata = JSON.stringify(saveFile);
    $http({ method: 'POST', url: rootURL + '/data/savefilecontent', data: inputjsondata, dataType: 'text', processData: false, async: false, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' } }).success(function (data) {
        alert("File successfuly saved.");

    });
};
       $scope.attachedFile = [];
        $scope.attachedFile.push({
            "filename": $scope.fileContent.FileName,
            "filetype": $scope.attachedFile.FileType,
            "filesize": $scope.fileContent.Size
        });
```

With above code i can read a file from browser and uploading in my server and ...
even below code can make a JSON file for me and i can upload my file with Name, Size and Type:

```
$scope.attachedFile = [];
        $scope.attachedFile.push({
            "filename": $scope.fileContent.FileName,
            "filetype": $scope.attachedFile.FileType,
            "filesize": $scope.fileContent.Size
        });
```

but with below codes, i can make a table with 3 rows and want to show to the user the description of uploaded files in any rows of my table (1 row is for one file description)
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;

```
$("#DocFile").on("click", function () {

    counter = $('#myTable tr').length - 2;

    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";
    cols += '<td><input type="text" "name="name'  + counter + '" /></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" "name="size'  + counter + '" /></td>';        
    cols += '<td><input type="text" "name="type'  + counter + '" /></td>';

    cols += '<td><img src="images/template/Icons/closec.png" class="ibtnDel" title="Rmoving Row" style="cursor:pointer" /></td>';

    newRow.append(cols);
    $("table.letter-list").append(newRow);
    counter++;
});

$("table.letter-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();

    counter -= 1
    $('#DocFile').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "Add Row");
});
```

I can show to the user my first file uploaded description, but i cant show other uploaded files detail to them. 
I need to send all of my uploaded file data into a JSON and at the end show to the user the descriptions of all uploaded file in different rows of a table.
I dont know how to do this.
it confused me...
Sry for long text

Comment: I added my JQuery code. It creates my rows. but it couldn't push the data all of my new rows into a JSON file.

Comment: jquery and angularjs ARE javascript. However angualar uses a completely different approach than jquery. What do you want? jquery or angular? Both together is not a good idea.

Comment: I prefer to use Jquery. I can make, but i cant send the data of my new rows to my old JSON

Comment: Yes, i can see that your example is in jquery. And basically it is working. Now what is the issue? Can you use this plunker to further describe your question http://plnkr.co/edit/jn9lOzhxI4Qfm4W9WB3Y?p=preview ? And plz remove the angular tag from your question because this has nothing to do with it. Btw, I also can't see any json in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what you  want to do exactly.

But the best way (in my opinion) is using table

Add this to ur HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in formData.Attachments" style="width:25px; height:20px;">
<td>{{item.Filename}}</td>
<td>{{item.filesize}}</td>
<td><button ng-click="deleteItem($index)" id="removefile" style="cursor:pointer" align="center/></td>
</tr>
```

and your script

```
    var fileContent = "";
    for (var i=0; i < $scope.attachedFile.length; i++) {
    fileContent = $scope.attachedFile[i].fileContent;

    $scope.attachedFile.push({
        "filename": $scope.fileContent[i].FileName,
        "filesize": $scope.fileContent.Size
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

at the time of seeing this question it seems like everything but the table to json function is working. I'm not going to do your coding for you but i will show you how.

1. add another button next to docFile called submit.
2. Google html "table to json"
3. notice that http://plugins.jquery.com/tabletojson/ already exists
4. include the plugin
5. add to submit's onclick `var json = $('#myTable').tableToJSON();`
6. Not sure what you mean by writing a json file but now you have json you can send to your server via $.post. You cannot write a file on a clients machine from javascript directly though you can save a cookie or use HTML5 localStorage.